# Revise background color between UISearchBar and keyboard when the search filed get focus

Tags: ios

When the search field get focus, there is a black transparent view between search bar and keyboard, just like in iPhone email app, when you want to search an email, you click the search field first, there is a black transparent view appear. When you enter some words, there will be a result table view instead. And if you tap the view, the key board will close and the search filed will lose focus.

Now, I want to change the color of this view, for example to red transparent view. I have try it by using inputAccessoryView. But there still has a black one under it and I have to add tap action for it.

Is there any property can edit it?

Answer (score 2):

I find the answer by myself.

```
for (UIView *subview in searchBar.superview.subviews)
{
    if ([subview isKindOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"UISearchDisplayControllerContainerView")])
    {
        // in iOS7, this view is the view I want;
    }
    if ([subview isKindOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"UIControl")])
    {
        // before iOS7, this view is what I want;
    }
}
```

It seems to be very secretly, I don't know whether Apple allows or supports us to change it. Maybe it doesn't encourage us to do like above. But it can solve my problem.

Comment: Hi, I'm facing same issue, I'm adding subview to the UISearchDisplayControllerContainerView, wondering did you submit your app successfully with modifying UISearchDisplayControllerContainerView? Did Apple reject it? 

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I found the answer after we completed the project, so I can't answer your question.